Jungle adventure miniseries from the late 80's early 90's?
I cannot remember too much about it as I have not seen this series since 1991 on VHS. 
It took place in Central or South America. 
There were two kids about 12 years old a white boy and a black girl. I think they were traveling with adults on a boat through the jungle or rain forest.
There was one scene early on where the kids were exploring an old Mayan ruin or pyramid. The scene I remember most is when they were sleeping in the jungle and I think the boy wakes up and puts on his shoes without checking them and someone says, it might have been the girl "you should always check your shoes before putting them on". 
The girl ends up being stung by a scorpion while leaning against a tree and thats where the last episode I saw ended. There was one more episode after this but I never saw it.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Also, was this animated or live action?

It was live action.
